# How to display Commenter is online or offline in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, comments

I have my site in WordPress, in which whenever I published new post there is a option for user comments. I have seen that there are so many comments on my each post now I want to reply for some comments for this I have to check which Commenter is online in real time so I can reply him first.

I have selected an option for comments only for registered users by using default setting in WordPress.

one important thing is that I am using **WP-UserOnline** plugin to display list of registered users that are online in real time.

I have searched many terms for this, but on web there no no such option to do that.

I tried with this code which i put into my **class-walker-comment.php** file

```
<?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    echo 'Online';
} else {
    echo 'Offline';
}
?>
```

But this `is_user_logged_in()` fuction is checking only current user.

but I want to display the status of commenter and status should be visible for everyone like the image given below.

please check the image given below.

[image]

Comment: Well then I suggest you start by looking at how your WP-UserOnline plugin gathers this information. (It is likely a simple database query, that filters users by the timestamp of their last request made.)

Comment: this is a duplicate of your own many previous questions....you are not getting answers to this because you are neglecting to learn how log in works, it is client side rather than server side so for example you need a method when someone visits your site and is logged in, to store this information somewhere with an expire time and assume the person is logged in..